# How to create UTF characters dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, node.js, character, utf

I'm trying to use a variable and \u to create an UTF character with Node.js.

```
var code = '0045';
console.log('\u0045', '\u' + code);
```

But the output becomes

```
E u0045
```

How do I make it

```
E E
```

How do I create the character and store it in a variable?

Comment: Why don't you use `String.fromCharCode(n)`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `String.fromCharCode`:

```
String.fromCharCode(0x0045)
String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0045', 16))
```